# When I deploy my web project on IIS, I get the following error

Tags: asp.net, iis, iis-7, iis-7.5

When i deploy my web project after publishing, on IIS. it gives me the following error.

### Server Error in '/' Application.

Could not load file or assembly 'System.Web' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

**Description:** An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

**Exception Details:** System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Web' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

**Source Error:**

An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.

**Assembly Load Trace:** The following information can be helpful to determine why the assembly 'System.Web' could not be loaded.

WRN: Assembly binding logging is turned OFF.
To enable assembly bind failure logging, set the registry value [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog] (DWORD) to 1.
Note: There is some performance penalty associated with assembly bind failure logging.
To turn this feature off, remove the registry value [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog].

Comment: I have published, the project .. now when I host it on IIS it gives me this error.... in localhost it is al right and working fine.

Comment: it seems you don't have asp.net installed

Comment: @MatteoSp what does that mean ? it is installed .net framework 4.5

Comment: ASP.Net appears as component under IIS on Windows features (on Windows 7) or on Server Manager/Features (on Windows 2008/2012). Is it installed?

Comment: @MatteoSp yes it is installed...

Comment: is this because of .net framework versions?

Comment: **Problem solved** The problem was because,  it could't find the required assembly for .net frmework 4.5 in system.web e.g.. **<add assembly="System.Design, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B03F5F7F11D50A3A"/>** and i changed the  **Version=4.5.0.0** to **Version=4.0.0.0** and it worked fine :)

Answer (score 0):

Try the following (If using 64 bit IIS - replace framework by framework 64):-

1. Run command prompt as admin.

2a. If using version 3.5 Type

```
cd c:\windows\microsoft.net\framework\v2.0.50727
```

and press enter.

2b. If using version 4.0 or 4.5 type

```
cd c:\windows\microsoft.net\framework\v4.0.30319
```

and press enter.
3. Type

```
 aspnet_regiis -i
```

and press enter.